# Add JSch 0.1.54 JAR dependency to IDE artifact generation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsch, artifacts

I am attempting to add JSch 0.1.54 as a dependency to my Java project in IntelliJ. However, when I build my JAR artifact and run the application via the command line, I am encountering an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSch

The stack trace indicates that this occurs at the point of JSch instantiation, e.g.:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
```

This runs perfectly fine when I run it inside the IDE and only errors once I have packaged the JAR and run that from the command line.

I have added the JAR dependency to the Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies tab, and checked the export checkbox among many other configurations. The same occurs when I attempt to build this in Eclipse. What am I possibly missing here that would cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine the JSch jar dependency is not getting included in your jar package. Not completely familiar with IntelliJ, but look for an option something like "create runnable jar".

Comment: As it turns out this is the issue in Eclipse. While this doesn't necessarily help me with IntelliJ it gets me what I need to get the job done. Thanks for the help!